# GroupBy or Aggregate rows to return a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I'd like to group the rows by a maximum date. The dataset looks something like this: (the `date` column has been converted to datetime format)

```
species   date          breed        

cat       2019-01-01    Ragdoll
dog       2018-02-14    Pomeranian
dog       NaT           Huskey
cat       2017-05-25    Maine Coon
dog       2019-12-31    Shiba Inu
cat       NaT           Russian Blue
```

I want to create a new dataframe based on species and the maximum date for the species, like this (I would no longer need the `breed` column):

```
species    date

cat        2019-01-01
dog        2019-12-31
```

I was thinking of using a groupby statement like

```
df_pets_max_date =  df_pets.groupby(['species'])['date'].max()
```

but this doesn't quite give me what I need. It seems to output a series and not a dataframe, and the column structure is gone. I don't know if some sort of aggregate function would be better. What's the best way to go about getting this result?

Comment: You can either `reset_index` afterwards, or in this case specify `as_index=False` in the groupby

Comment: Add `.reset_index()` at the end